# Video streaming from multiple users in Django

Tags: python, django, webrtc

I am developing an exam platform website where people can create exams and take exams. I almost finished the examination part and wanted to add a proctoring system. I want that when people start any quiz, their video is displayed on the examiner's side. That is, when the users press (ex.) the "Start Quiz" button, their video is turned on. And examiners can watch all the exam passers in some url. I found that I could use OpenCV to do this, but couldn't figure out how to get multiple video sharings from different users. Please suggest me any ideas. What should I learn? Can this be implemented in Django?

Comment: Yes it can be implemented in Django. You might be well served by looking at web sockets on the front end and something like django-channels to handle websockets on the backend.

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts thanks for your advice! I'll definitely look at them

Comment: No worries at all - just a tip, your question is quite broad for an SO question. You're essentially asking the SO community how you could build something like Google Hangouts - where one person can watch multiple video streams or screen shares at once. It's quite complex. So I'm not sure you'll get anything better than exploratory comments like mine. But definitely, good luck!